# Weird large K symbol

Tags: notation, fractions, continued-fractions

Take a look at this symbol:

$$ \pi=3 + \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\large{\mathrm K}}} \frac{(2k-1)^2} 6 $$

Does it look familiar to you? If so please help me!

Comment: May I ask where you saw this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is the notation for a [continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html).
In general:
$$b_0 + \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\large{\mathrm K}}} \left(\frac{a_k}{b_k}\right)=b_0 + \cfrac{a_1}{b_1 + \cfrac{a_2}{b_2 + \cfrac{a_3}{b_3 + \cfrac{a_4}{b_4 + \ddots\,}}}}$$
Therefore, the continued fraction representation you have written above for $\pi$ is:
$$\pi=3 + \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\large{\mathrm K}}} \frac{(2k-1)^2}{6}=3 + \cfrac{1^2}{6 + \cfrac{3^2}{6 + \cfrac{5^2}{6 + \cfrac{7^2}{6 + \ddots\,}}}}$$
A proof of this result can be found on pages 399-401 of [this document](http://www.gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc.skole.hr/upload/gimnazija-izdijankoveckoga-kc/multistatic/387/EleAna.pdf) by Paul Loya.

Comment: An interesting aspect of this notation is that the apparent sequence of fractions $ \frac {a_k_} {b_k_}  $ is not actually used. Given that, I find this notation rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 32):

The given symbol is sometimes used for an infinite [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Notation), it seems to have been designed by [Carl Friedrich Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss).

Comment: A large Sigma for Summe (sum) by Euler, a large Pi for Product (product) by Gauß, a large Kappa for Kettenbruch (continued fraction) by Gauß as well. Neat! Obvious abbreviations are obvious.

Comment: Produkt* is Product in German.