# what is the large K notation？

Tags: notation

It says it is called as “notation of Carl Friedrich Gauss”.However，I cant find any more detail of this notation.Can any one please tell me its formal name and its property.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{K}$ ?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179834/weird-large-k-symbol/2179847#2179847)

Comment: @RafaBudría oh，thx！